# How do I connect a Google Cloud SQL database to Minecraft's CoreProtect plugin?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, minecraft

I'm attempting to connect a Minecraft servers CoreProtect database to a Google Cloud SQL database (which is allowed by the plugin) although I can't seem to get the right information needed. I've managed to achieve this connection with a previous host (although I had to move to Google Cloud due to a need of more storage) but I just can't figure it out with Google Cloud.

Here's the information needed to connect on the plugin's end:

```
# MySQL is optional and not required.
# If you prefer to use MySQL, enable the following and fill out the fields.
use-mysql: true
table-prefix: co_
mysql-host: 
mysql-port: 3306
mysql-database: 
mysql-username: 
mysql-password:
```

It'd be great if anyone has any answers or experience in linking these? 
Feel free to ask for any additional information which may help. (I'm also very new to Google Cloud SQL, so my apologies if some of this doesn't make sense)

Comment: The documentation at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app should explain everything. Please follow that, and then tell us exactly where you get stuck.

Comment: The only way I could think of connecting it to the server then would be by using public IP? Although the server I'm attempting to connect to doesn't provide an applicable IP address to authorize it.

Comment: Which service are you running this code on? Normally you want to use the Cloud SQL Proxy instead of IP addressing.

Comment: It's running off of a remote minecraft server, not local hosted

Comment: If you can run an additional process, the @JohnHanley solution is the right one!

Comment: I've been trying to follow the document provided although I've been quite thrown off by some terminology used.. I'm still a huge newbie so sorry for my ignorance in what may be a simple issue...